# TypeError: 'OpenStackNetwork' object does not support indexing

Tags: python, openstack, libcloud

I have a function:

```
 node = self.conn.NodeDriver.create_node(name = utils.VM_NAME %
 (course_id, names[i], idx), 
          image = images[i], 
          size = sizes[i],
          networks = network[i], 
          ex_keyname = key_pair.name)
 self.nodes.append(node)
```

with networks parameter, I assign a list like this:

```
<OpenStackNetwork id="d271340d-a55c-4470-af22-42640072917f" name="n-89-net2" cidr="None">
```

when compile I get error:

```
    networks = network[i],
TypeError: 'OpenStackNetwork' object does not support indexing
```

please teach me how to fix this. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you just assigned a single object to networks parameter, which definitely will not work, try something like [OpenStackNetwork()]

Note: put your real object instead of my example

Comment: and I get error:    server_params['flavorRef'] = kwargs.get('size').id
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: I recommend you to look into document and the function create_node() you just called to check what it is needed, rather than modify->have problem->ask